# How to uninstall .Net language pack in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, .net-framework, language-pack

I have an English Windows 7. For some reason I think I installed a Dutch Language pack for .NET. I'm a C# web developer and now all error messages in my web applications are in Dutch (at my PC).
How do I tell .NET to show English errors to me, or how could I delete the language pack?

I've looked in Control Panel / Program and Features (and installed updates) and I tried Turn Windows Features on or off, but I could not find a way to uninstall the Dutch .NET language pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it seemed as easy as uninstalling the Dutch windows 7 language pack.